# Why isn't my table partial rendering?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, viewmodel

I am trying to use a partial view to build a table in my MVC5 application, here is what I have:

**ViewModel**

```
public class ResultsViewModel
{
    public Results FirstPartyResults { get; set; }

    public Results SecondPartyResults { get; set; }

    public Results ThirdPartyResults { get; set; }
}
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
@model App.ViewModels.ResultsViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Start Election";
}

<div id="partialTable">
    @{ Html.RenderPartial("_TablePartial", Model); }
</div>
```

```
<script>
    $(document)
        .ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                    url: '/Home/StartElection',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: "test",
                })
                .done(function(partialViewResult) {
                    $("partialTable").html(partialViewResult);
                });
        });
</script>
```

**_TablePartial.cshtml**

```
@model App.ViewModels.ResultsViewModel  

<div class="page-header">
    <h1>Party Results</h1>
</div>

<div id="partialTable">
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Party Code</th>
                <th>Number of Seats</th>
                <th>Overall Share of Votes
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @if (Model != null)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Model.FirstPartyResults.PartyCode
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Model.FirstPartyResults.NumberOfSeats
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Model.FirstPartyResults.ShareOfVotes
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Model.SecondPartyResults.PartyCode
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Model.SecondPartyResults.NumberOfSeats
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Model.SecondPartyResults.ShareOfVotes
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Model.ThirdPartyResults.PartyCode
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Model.ThirdPartyResults.NumberOfSeats
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Model.ThirdPartyResults.ShareOfVotes
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**Controller code**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult StartElection()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost] 
public ActionResult StartElection(string text)
{
    var scoreBoard = new ScoreBoard();

    var viewModel = scoreBoard.GetTopResults();

    return PartialView("_TablePartial", viewModel);
}
```

- I've set a break point at the controller, the view model object is created as expected
- I've also set a breakpoint in the partial at the condition checking of the `Model` is null & the code within is being executed

> The page is being rendered with the table heading but not the model table data - can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

**Note:** I am wanting the table to be updated over time through ajax calls - I'm not trying to do that (yet) here but explains why I have a `GET` action result and a `POST`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the partial view is inside a div with id `partialTable`

```
<div id="partialTable">
    @{ Html.RenderPartial("_TablePartial", Model); }
</div>
```

Here's where you're wrong

```
$("partialTable").html(partialViewResult);
```

You need to use `#` ([jQuery ID Selector](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)) to select the element by its id

```
$("#partialTable").html(partialViewResult);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, appreciated!